# TCM URI getting appended to image name while publishing in case of Dynamic Component Presentation

Tags: 2011, publishing, templating, multimedia

I have a Component which can be used as embedded content in one Component Template and can also be published dynamically with another Component Template.

The issue is while publishing only the Component it is appending TCM URI to the image name (image is a multimedia Component field) (due to `addBinary` in default finish action) while when we publish the Page containing the Component as embedded content, it is not appending the TCM URI.

Though we have got a workaround by pushing the images to package in case of Dynamic Component Presentation, I am not able to understand the behavior in case of static page. Is it automatically pushing the images to package?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using this Generic TBB in your package: https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx

Comment: No, we are just using the default TBB, but is it not the expected behavior or tridion to add tcm id to image names?

Comment: Which version of Tridion? I do not think so

Comment: Tridion 2011 SP1. In default finish action I can see a parameter for target folder for image in Template builder. not sure if this a custom TBB as I have seen this in custom tbb for dd4t.

Comment: Could be the case, you may try debugging the default finish action using Template Builder and the picture might be more clearer to you

Comment: I don't think the dynamic setting is the difference here, but rather a difference in the Template Building blocks or API calls. Are the templates from an older version of Tridion? For example, `PublishBinary()` will add (modified) TCM Urls to the end of binaries as [Chris Summers describes in this post](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx).

Comment: Hi Alvin, to simplify my question, I just want to know that if i use the default finish action provided by Tridion (i.e. which comes in template builder by default), will it append tcm id or not. is it the default behavior? I have already gone through the post by Chris summer but that is quite old and not sure if thats the behavior in Triond 2011/2013

Comment: I only saw tcm suffixes on published image paths with `PublishBinary()`, specifically in my case using XSLT CTs with Tridion R5.3. This would likely have been the same for Tridion 2009. Chris's post would apply to 2011 and later. The target structure group  parameter is part of the Default Finish Action TBB (specifically it's *not a folder*, though) per [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879).